# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value while reading from DS with fromCString

Tags: swift, sqlite, null, unsafe-pointers

I am reading from a dbtable and get an error at a specific position of the table. My sql is ok, because I could already read from the same table, but at a specific row I get an error and I would like to know howto handle this error. I am not looking for a solution to solve my db-issue, I am just looking for handling the error, so it doesn't crash.

I have the following code :

```
let unsafepointer=UnsafePointer<CChar>(sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2));
if unsafepointer != nil {
    sText=String.fromCString(unsafepointer)! // <<<<<< ERROR
} else {
   sText="unsafe text pointer is nil !";
}
```

I get an error:

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an  Optional value"

at line marked with `<<<<<< ERROR`.

The unsafe pointer's value is not `nil`:

```
pointerValue : 2068355072
```

How can I handle this error, so my app is not crashing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possible solution is this:

```
let unsafepointer=UnsafePointer<CChar>(sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2));
var sText = "unsafe text pointer is nil !";
if unsafepointer != nil{
    if let text = String.fromCString(unsafepointer) as String?{
        sText = text;
    }    
}
```

Comment: I get an syntax error in the if statement  "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UnsafePointer<CChar>' (aka 'UnsafePointer<Int8>')"

Comment: Thanks you very much. Helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
if sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2) != nil {                     
print("do something")
} else {
YourString = ""
}
```

Comment: Hi Miguel - can you explain why this answer is better than the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
let statementValue = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)
var sText = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&statementValue) {UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>($0)}
```

Comment: I do not understand. I have still the same problem and in sText, there is no text. sText is a UnsafeMutablePointer. Howto handle the error ?

Comment: What about now? Are you sure do you have a valid statement value?

Comment: I get an syntax error at the "if let ..." statement : "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>'". I am at Xcode 7.2

Comment: Thanks for helping. I could use the sample from "ciccioska".

Comment: Can you edit your proposed answer to expand on what this does and how it addresses the OP?